# Saving rake task in database to add in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, httparty

I am trying to save a rake task into my database to I can display the content in my view.

Here's the task:

```
desc "Fetch Digital Trends"
task :fetch_trends => :environment do
require 'nokogiri'
  require 'httparty'
  url = "http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    doc.css(".post").each do |item|
    title = item.at_css(".content h3").text
    link = item.at_css(".content h3 a")[:href]
    puts "#{title} - #{link}"
  end
end
```

It is possible to make this task run every hour to update the content?

Comment: Do you want to save the rake task in database?

Comment: Correct, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cron. Look at https://github.com/javan/whenever (Cron jobs in Ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

Method 1:

1. Read from database.
2. Write to a file in lib/tasks/name.rake
3. load the file
4. Execute the rake task

Method 2:

1. Load the string from the database
2. Use [eval](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/Eval-Running-Code-On-The-Fly.htm)

Comment: Sorry Vimsha, I do not understand what you mean. I have the above task that just needs to save into a table within my database every time the task is run.